# What causes the heap corruption in my method?

Tags: c++, c, heap-corruption

So I have tracked down an annoying heap corruption to a single method.

```
DWORD gdwCounter = 0;

TCHAR* GetName(const TCHAR* format, size_t len)
{
    len += (snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lu", gdwCounter) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    TCHAR *c = (TCHAR*)malloc(len);
    _stprintf_s(c, len, __TEXT("%s%lu"), format, gdwCounter);
    return c;
}
```

To make sure I found the correct method, I tried to change it and just copy the 'format' buffer it gets passed as an parameter to the output buffer. Heap corruption went away and everything was fine again.

I decided to look at the documentations of [snprintf](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-snprintf-snprintf-l-snwprintf-snwprintf-l?view=vs-2019) and [_stprintf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=vs-2019).

**snprintf** is supposed to return the required characters without the null-terminating character to actually print your buffer in a second call to it.

My *len* parameter already contains the full size (with null-terminating character) of *format*.

Also I couldn't find any hints to what is wrong in the documentation of **_stprintf_s**.

**So what am I missing?**

Edit: After further testing I found out that apparently **_stprintf_s** causes the error as snprintf does return the correct size.

Comment: You allocate a buffer big enough to print gdwCounter as long unsigned into it, then print the format into it as well. In other words, you should mallc len + strlen of format.

Comment: I call GetName like this: GetName(_T("String"), sizeof(_T("String")));
Shouldn't sizeof(_T("String")) + (snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lu", gdwCounter) * sizeof(TCHAR)); be enough for both format and gdwCounter?

Comment: It's 2019. `TCHAR` was obsolete by the time the Unicode library for **Windows 98** came out over 20 years ago. **Why are you using `TCHAR`?!?!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TCHAR* GetName(const TCHAR* format, size_t len)
{
    len += snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lu", gdwCounter);
    TCHAR *c = (TCHAR*)malloc(len*sizeof(TCHAR));
    _stprintf_s(c, len, __TEXT("%s%lu"), format, gdwCounter);
    return c;
}
```

[_stprintf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=vs-2019) takes the "*Maximum number of characters to store*" instead of maximum number of bytes.